# Ember custom conventions

Tags: ember.js

I'm build a list-view, which renders a list of records in a table. The list-view is build as a reusable mixin, and has a reusable template as well. I want the list-view to be as easy to use as possible, and not have to write too much code, to make it work - but only overwrite what I want to change.

Idealy I only want to tell the controller (or perhaps even better) the router, that it's going to render a list-view, and only render custom template, if I have one defined.

Example:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import MixinList from '../../mixins/mixin-list';

export default Ember.Route.extend(MixinList, {
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('category');
  }
});
```

Currently I have to write this code, to make the list-view work:

**Categories route:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('category');
  }
});
```

**Categories controller:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import MixinList from '../../mixins/mixin-list';

export default Ember.Controller.extend(MixinList, {
  actions: {
    itemAction: function(actionName, item) {
      if (actionName === 'edit') {
        this.transitionToRoute('categories.edit', item.get('id'));
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**Categories template:**

```
<h1>Categories</h1>
{{partial 'mixin-list'}}
```

Is it possible to setup conventions, so routes which are using a specific mixin, are given a default controller and template, if they arent added to the project by the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further research (and some fresh eyes), I found the solution:

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    var currentController = this.container.lookup('controller:' + this.routeName);

    if (currentController.isGenerated) {
      currentController.reopen(MixinList);
      this.render('mixin-list-view');
    }
    else {
      this.render();
    }
  }
});
```

That allows me to only define the route, and include the mixin, and let that mixin do the magic:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import MixinList from '../../mixins/mixin-list';

export default Ember.Route.extend(MixinList, {
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('category');
  }
});
```

The important part here, is the **renderTemplate** method, and the lookup to the *currentController*. The *currentController* exposes a property, that tells if it's autogenerated (not explicitly created by the user). In that case, we can overwrite the rendered template, and even add functionallity to the controller - for example by adding a mixin to the controller (.reopen(...)).